# DLL with Python

Tags: python, dll

I am trying to call functions from a DLL

```
function oziRepositionWP(Number:integer;lat,lon:double):integer;stdcall;
```

I have written the code in python

```
no = c_int(1)
lat = c_double(34.00962)
lon = c_double(74.80067)

var =windll.OziAPI.oziRepositionWP(byref(no),byref(lat),byref(lon))
```

But i get the message

```
var =windll.OziAPI.oziRepositionWP(byref(no),byref(lat),byref(lon))
ValueError: Procedure probably called with not enough arguments (8 bytes missing)
```

where am i going wrong please help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what language `function oziRepositionWP(Number:integer;lat,lon:double):integer;stdcall;` actually is. Is it Delphi? Anyway, the signature looks like it accepts all arguments by value; however, in your actual call, all values are passed by reference. Assuming, you are working in 32 bits, you are passing 3 pointer values (a 32 bit each => 12 bytes), but the function takes an integer (32 bit) and two doubles (64 bit) => 20 bytes.

However, this is just an educated guess, as long as the implementation language of `OziAPI` is not defined.